# Route cloud not find driver

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am new whit Laravel and write my first `route` , but have my first problem.

Server : Php5.6 + Mysql + apache2 , Linux Mint

First install whit :

```
 composer create-project laravel/laravel test 5.0 --prefer-dist
```

And permisions in :

```
 chmod 777 -R ./storage/ && chmod 777 -R ./bootstrap/
```

In route php

```
Route::get('/test',function (){
    echo "Batman like the black color.";
});
```

This can go to direction `localhost/<nameproyect>/test`. This not go , but i write for check this route is create fine , write `php artisan route:list`.

This is a broblem:

```
[PDOException]         
  could not find driver
```

In php.ini , i have :

```
extension = pdo.so
extension = pdo_mysql.so
```

**Solution :**

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

**And other problem :**

```
[2016-11-10 16:15:24] local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

**Solution** whit `.env` :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install MySQL PDO driver installing php5-mysql

> sudo apt-get install php5-mysql

Comment: I have this problem  `[PDOException]                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` , but this cuestion is finished , thx.

I write `sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Comment: Is homestead your user?